# Tortoise SVN doesn't commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svncommit

I'm a Android developer, I use Android Studio or Eclipse for development and I use Tortoise for versioning. The problem came up the last few weeks and is that when I create a new class or activity and then when I'm trying to commit it, it doesn't. The specific files never shown on the window in order to select them and commit them. I tried both window and cmd and nothing works. Actually I didn't know until a colleague complained about not committing completely the projects. I do the same thing like the past 3 years that I use Tortoise and was working fine. When finish my job and on the root folder I select 'Commit'. I'm doing something wrong? Is there an other way to do so? Do I have to change any preferences? My current version number is around 3500 and I saw that the local sqlite .db is around 300MB. Also I noticed that if the file in close to the root path Tortoise discovers and finds the specific file (Example: TortoiseSVN\MyProject\thefile.txt). If it is deep it doesn't (Example: TortoiseSVN\MyProject\MySubProject\android\srv\test\myfile.java).

Comment: You're not asked for a commit message? I'd do the commit within Eclipse or ADT.

Comment: In the commit window, is "unversioned files" checked? If it is, are these files being created in a directory that is currently part of your repository? If they are, do they match the svn:ignore setting on that directory? If not, do they match your "global ignore" settings?

Comment: Have you added the new code to the repository? (Check the documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

Use Eclipse plugin called 'Subclipse'. You can find it in the Help>Eclipse MarketPlace...

It is very intuitive and better than Tortoise.

Comment: Why is Subclipse better than TortoiseSVN?

Comment: This does not sound like a solution: OP has probably made a mistake in his use of Subversion which have the same effect in any GUI.